# Broken php redirect function

Tags: php

I am building a social networking project for a portfolio I'm working on. I'm currently stumped as I am working on building a status update form and code that is working elsewhere in the application is not working here. I have an add_post function for users to create status updates and I'm trying to get the function to redirect back to profile.php where the user_id is the same as the user that is logged in. My problem is every time I submit the form with user_id 3 it returns the profile page for user_id 9.

My code for add_post function:

```
function add_post(){

if(isset($_POST['publish'])){
$post_user_id = escape_string($_POST['post_user_id']);
    $post_content = escape_string($_POST['post_content']);
    $query = query("INSERT INTO posts(post_user_id, post_content)
    VALUES('{$post_user_id}', '{$post_content}')");
        $last_id = last_id();
        confirm($query);
        while ($row = fetch_array($query)){
            redirect("profile.php?id={$row['user_id']}");
        }
}}
```

I'm a little lost because this method I have used to redirect the user works fine in the login form. See here:

```
function login(){
 //check if the submit button has been pressed
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //create variables and assign values from the username and password fields in the login form
    $username= escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password= hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
    //check them against the values held in the database
    $query= query("SELECT*FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'");
    confirm($query);

    //use the num_rows function to work out whether there is a match - or not
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        set_message("Your username or password is incorrect. Please try again.");
        redirect("login.php");
    }else{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        while ($row = fetch_array($query)){
            redirect("profile.php?id={$row['user_id']}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

The redirect function code:

```
function redirect($location){
header("Location: $location");
}
```

Comment: Your code has multiple problems: 1. you should never use SQL statements like this, use prepared statements instead 2. what does `confirm` do? 3. what do you expect to receive if you're fetching the result of an `INSERT`. 4. `fetch_array` with a query as parameter is definitely no built in function in PHP, so this has to be your custom code or some undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are running an `INSERT` query then you are trying to get values from it. That's not what you want... if the ID returned by the `INSERT` is where you want to redirect, then just change:

```php
$query = query("INSERT INTO posts(post_user_id, post_content)
    VALUES('{$post_user_id}', '{$post_content}')");
        $last_id = last_id();
        confirm($query);
        while ($row = fetch_array($query)){
            redirect("profile.php?id={$row['user_id']}");
        }
```

to

```php
$query = query("INSERT INTO posts(post_user_id, post_content)
    VALUES('{$post_user_id}', '{$post_content}')");
        $last_id = last_id();
         redirect("profile.php?id={$last_id}");
```

Otherwise, you need to make a `SELECT` query which will return a row that includes a column named `user_id` (which is what you are asking for on `redirect("profile.php?id={$row['user_id']}")`)... an SQL `INSERT` will never return that

Comment: Thank you. Your solution for redirecting with last_id worked neatly. 
I also forgot the query was inserting data instead of retrieving it, whoops ':D
Edit: It worked but is redirecting to the last post_id but I understand how to fix this now that I know the query wasn't set up properly.

Comment: @abcd yeah, i didn't really care to check your "logic" or database or something... i just figured out that you were retrieving the wrong data from an `INSERT` query. If you want to redirect to the user id from the post... then you already have that in the variable `$post_user_id` and can use that

Comment: I got this working the way I wanted using that exact solution. I seen I was already storing the user_id in post_user_id and had a bit of a meltdown. 

Thanks again!